# How generate java code to src folder not to bin nor target?

Tags: java, javapoet

I'm using JavaPoet to generate some classes. All correct! But I need to generate that code into src folder, not into target nor bin nor classes folder

Now, I'm using follow code to write classes:

```
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getURLs();
File root = new File(urls[0].toURI());  // this is 'target' folder
File source = new File(root, packageName.replace(".", "/").concat("/").concat(className).concat(".java"));

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(source);
JavaFile.builder(packageName, spec).build().writeTo(writer);
```

Comment: This is unclear - you can pass anything you like into the constructor `FileWriter`, so what's the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to get src folder in runtime. That line using classloader takes only class folder. I'd like to generate code into src.

Comment: Java has no concept of a source folder at runtime.  So you'd need to pass it in a parameter to your application.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How to get that?

Comment: You need to use your build tool e.g. maven or gradle -- they know the src folder at the moment of building and are able to pass it as a argument to your program or at least write in a file near your classes or inside your jar.

Comment: It's getting closer. Thanks again. Now I'll research how to do that with maven.

Comment: You need preprocessors

Comment: With maven you should never generate code into the `src` folder and in turn check it into the source repository. Generate your code into `generated-sources` directory under the target. You can then either use eclipse plugin which will automatically add `generated-sources` as source folder or manually add it into your IDE. Also Maven `package` command will compile any source found under `generated-sources` and put into your artifact.